# Change user storage folder from /home to somewhere else

Tags: linux, command-line, storage

I want to let a user take huge space on another drive. Is there a command that I can move the user from `/home` folder on a mounted drive in `/mnt` folder?

If I do move folder `/home/foo` to `/mnt/sra/home/foo` folder and I change the line:

```
foo:x:999:999::/home/foo:/usr/bin/git-shell
```

to:

```
foo:x:999:999::/mnt/sra/home/foo:/usr/bin/git-shell
```

Will it works?

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I move a user's home directory?

You can do this using `usermod` (modify a user account)

```
usermod -m -d /mnt/sra/home/foo username
```

- `-d`, `--home` *HOME_DIR*

  The user's new login directory.
- -m, --move-home

  Move the content of the user's home directory to the new location.

Source [usermod(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod)